# Redirecting Pages: Names to Standard Address

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have WordPress installed in the root of a website, and recently enabled a custom permalink structure just for the sake of having good looking page URLs (only pages are used in this website, no posts at all — it's not a blog). Unfortunately this is causing some problems with other parts of the website, outside WordPress.

So I'd like to go the manual way: and redirect URLs like `/my-page` to `/?page_id=32` just for a selected amount of pages. Is it possible to do that using the *.htaccess* file? What would the rules look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you're redirecting pages from Wordpress to other URLs, you can use .htaccess. But it's probably easier to use a plugin to redirect rather than edit .htaccess.

See [WordPress › Redirection « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) to easily set up redirects and log redirects, errors, and more.